# Printing vertical histogram

Tags: c, arrays, histogram

I am trying to print a vertical histogram that counts the frequency of each digit input by the user.
I store the frequency first as follows:

```
 int a[10];  //array
 int c;      //store input from getchar
 int i;      //loop variable

 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 {

    a[i]=0;   //initialize to 0
 }
 while((c=getchar())!=EOF)  //read character
 {
    ++a[c-'0'];
 }
```

Next, I try to draw a vertical histogram.

```
for(i=10;i>0;i--)  //asssumed max limit of frequency is 10
{
  int j;          //iterate through the array
  for(j=0;j<10;j++)
{
 if(a[j]==i)     //if frequency of any element in array matches i 
 {
  printf("* \t");
  --a[j];       //decrement array element frequency value
 }
 else
 printf(" \t");  //no action
 }
 printf("\n");   //next line
}
```

The problem is when I try to print the histogram, I get a blank screen. I have tested it with horizontal histogram and it works.

Comment: Please post a[MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking exactly your code, formatting it for readability, and adding a check to ensure that only digits are used to avoid breaking things further, it worked. The check was not necessary for functionality, but it's a good idea to avoid writing out of the bounds of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    int a[10];  //array
    int c;      //store input from getchar
    int i;      //loop variable

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        a[i]=0;   //initialize to 0
    }
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)  //read character
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
            ++a[c - '0'];
    }

    for(i=10;i>0;i--)  //asssumed max limit of frequency is 10
    {
        int j;          //iterate through the array
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            if(a[j]==i)     //if frequency of any element in array matches i 
            {
                printf("* \t");
                --a[j];       //decrement array element frequency value
            }
            else
                printf(" \t");  //no action
        }
        printf("\n");   //next line
    }
}
```

Result:

```
$ ./a
0123456789666338592






                                                *
                        *                       *
                *       *               *       *               *       *
*       *       *       *       *       *       *       *       *       *
```

For reference, this was compiled for Cygwin.
I've also modified your source code in a few ways to correspond with some of the practices that I follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10] = {0}; // While use a for to initialize to 0 when you can do it easily?
    int i;
    char c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (isdigit(c))    // Never trust the user
            a[c - '0']++;  // Changed for readability, make it clear that we are incrementing the value, not the pointer.
    }

    for(i = 10; i > 0; --i)
    {
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            // Made flow a little clearer
            if(a[j] >= i)
                putchar('*');
            else
                putchar(' ');
            putchar('\t');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

What you do is of course up to you, I just personally find this more consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Thomas. Will keep these things in mind while writing code in future.